# How to add check box in Angular 2 ng2-smart-table?

Tags: angular

I am writing

```
checkbox: {
      title: 'Re-Assiiiiign',
      type: 'html',
      valuePrepareFunction: (value) => { return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.input); },

      filter: false
 },
```

and

```
public input: string = '<input type="checkbox"></input>';
constructor(private _hrdashboardservice: HRDashboardService, private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer){
}
```

but the check box cannot be clicked.  Anybody knows any other way to solve add checkbox in ng2-smart-table?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add in your table model

```
selectMode: 'multi'
```

[Example ng2-smart-table](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/src/app/pages/examples/various/basic-example-multi-select.component.ts)